# Relational tables: a 3rd table with relations

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-key-relationship, create-table, relational

I'm building a php page that will show an specific banner when the user enters his/her phone number in a form field.

So here's my logic for the database:

Table phones with fields: id, name of user and phone number.
Table banners with fields: id, banner's name/title and banner (path to the image).
Table relation with fields: here's where the phone number should be related to a banner and where I need your help :)

And here's my logic for the php page:

-form gets the phone number
-I query the data base
-I show the banner related to the phone number entered in the form.

Below is the code for the table creation so far .. as you'll see don't know how to advance.

Thanks a million

```
    CREATE TABLE phones(

id_phone INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

nombre VARCHAR(30),

number INT (9),

PRIMARY KEY (id_phone)

) TYPE = INNODB;


CREATE TABLE banners (

id_banners INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

id_phone INT NOT NULL,

name VARCHAR(250),

banner VARCHAR(250),

PRIMARY KEY(id_phone),

INDEX (id_phone),

FOREIGN KEY (id_phone) REFERENCES clientes(id_phone)

) TYPE = INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all what's the question?
What can I mention at this step is, does the relation between this entities is one to one? If so, you'd better put all this data into one single table.

++

```
CREATE TABLE phones(
phone_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30),
number INT (9),
PRIMARY KEY (id_phone)
) TYPE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE banners (
banner_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
phone_id INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(250),
banner VARCHAR(250),
PRIMARY KEY(id_phone),
INDEX (id_phone),
FOREIGN KEY (phone_id) REFERENCES clientes(phone_id)
) TYPE = INNODB;
```

and the query would be:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM clients LEFT JOIN banners USING(phone_id) WHERE clients.number='.$number.'";
```

Comment: It's a good question, I'm such a newbie that I better explain myself with an image: http://217.116.9.130/2tables.gif

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it seems that each phone number has only one banner associated with it. Therefore, delete the `banners.id_banners` field and add a `phones.id_banners`

Then to select the data, you can do a JOIN:

```
SELECT phones.id_phone, phones.nombre, phones.number, 
banners.id_banners, banners.name, banners.banner
JOIN banners ON phones.id_banners = banners.id_banners
WHERE phone = '123-456-789'
```